# Navigation Bar stays while Pushing and Poping the View Controllers creating a weird White color Effect while transition

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `navigationController` which is being used to move between my `ViewControllers`.

I have it setup normally and I am using Xib's for each View Controller.

```
extension UINavigationController{

    func setup(){

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            self.navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

        self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red


        self.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = true
        self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

        self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(hexString: "#373839")

    }
}
```

This is the extension I am using for my UINavigation Controller.

And in the pushed View (Second View), I need to have different Left and right buttons so I am hiding the navigation backbitten and having a custom code to setup my buttons.

```
func setUI(){


        self.navigationController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

        let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))

        let hostStr = host
        print(hostStr)
        let searchImage    = UIImage(named: "Search_Icon3")!
        let notificationImage  = UIImage(named: "Notification_Icon3")!
        let profileImage  = UIImage(named: "test_Profile")!
        let backImage  = UIImage(named: "Back_Icon3")!

        let searchButton   = UIBarButtonItem(image: searchImage,  style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(searchViewButtonPressed(_:)))
        let notificationButton   = UIBarButtonItem(image: notificationImage,  style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(notificationViewButtonPressed(_:)))
        let profileButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: profileImage,  style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(profileViewButtonPressed(_:)))
        let backButton   = UIBarButtonItem(image: backImage,  style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backButtonPressed(_:)))



        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [profileButton,notificationButton,searchButton]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(hexString: "#373839")
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton

        self.setValues()
    }
```

But when I push from `ViewController` 1 to 2 and Pop from 2 to 1 I get this weird Nav bar present effect between transition

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Your status bar color get changed, that's the reason behind this woerdness. Stick to a single color status bar design would resolve this.

Comment: Sir but I have no code to change the status bar in any of the view controllers ? Is there a way I can keep the status bar color constant.